# Ansible - Using combine() and with_nested to return a one-to-one mapping

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook:

```
---
- name: painters
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    result: {}
  tasks:

    - name: combine painters
      set_fact:
        result: "{{result | combine( { item[0]: item[1] } ) }}"
      with_nested:
        - ['pablo', 'bob']
        - ['picasso', 'ross']

    - name: print grouping
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result }}"
```

I want it to return:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "bob": "ross",
        "pablo": "picasso"
    }
}
```

but it's returning:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "bob": "ross",
        "pablo": "ross"
    }
}
```

How do I make the action of the `combine` command and `with_nested` output a 1:1 mapping for the two painters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [with_together](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-parallel-sets-of-data).  If I have:

```
---
- name: painters
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    result: {}
  tasks:
    - name: combine painters
      set_fact:
        result: "{{result | combine( { item[0]: item[1] } ) }}"
      with_together:
        - ['pablo', 'bob']
        - ['picasso', 'ross']

    - name: print grouping
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result }}"
```

I get:

PLAY [painters] ****************************************************************

```
TASK [combine painters] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'bob', u'ross'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'pablo', u'picasso'])

TASK [print grouping] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "bob": "ross", 
        "pablo": "picasso"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```